How to reconcile the mathematical and physical description of the Poincare algebra
I've asked the following question on physics.SE but it attracted little interest. So I thought I'd ask here:
The Poincare group is the semidirect product:

$Pnc := Trans(1, 3) \rtimes O(1, 3)$.

I am using Pnc as an abbreviation for the Poincare group as there's no standard abbreviation for this grp and likewise $\mathfrak{pnc}$ for it's lie algebra in the following. According to the math books I've looked at, the Lie algebra for this is simply the semidirect product of the corresponding Lie algebras:

$\mathfrak{pnc} := \mathfrak{trans}(1, 3) \rtimes \mathfrak{o}(1, 3)$.

However, when I look at the physical literature, the Poincare algebra is given by a set of commutation relations:
$[J_m, P_n] = i \epsilon_{mnk}P_k$
$[J_i, P_0] = 0$
$[K_i, P_k] = i \eta_{ik} P_0$
$[K_i, P_0] = -i P_i$
$[J_m, J_n] = i \epsilon_{mnk}J_k$
$[J_m, K_n] = i \epsilon_{mnk}K_k$
$[K_m, K_n] = -i \epsilon_{mnk}J_k$
Obviously the mathematical description is much simpler than the physical description using commutators. Nevertheless the latter is useful in computations as well as understanding the physical literature.
Q. How do we go from the mathematical description to the physical description of the Poincare algebra?

$J_n$ and $K_n$ form a basis of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ with $J_n$ moreover a basis of a copy of  $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ contained inside. $P_n$ is a basis of the translations
